# Redirecting appcmd output to a variable

Tags: shell, cmd, appcmd

I am trying to run the following:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %A IN ('C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list app /site.name:"car" /xml | C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list vdir /vdir.name:"car/" /text:physicalPath') DO SET Variable=%A
```

But get the following error:

```
| was unxepected at this time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data must be piped from a process to the other, you need to escape the pipe character. It should be `^|`

If what you need to do is execute both commands, replace the pipe character with `^&`, the command concatenation operator, also escaped

Comment: that's great thanks. One follow up question please - I'd like the command window to stay open after running the command above. But it won't, not even with a pause. Thanks

Comment: @StuHarper, is this a batch file? if not, how are you running the command?

Comment: @StuHarper, inside a batch file (cmd), the `for` replaceable parameter need also to be escaped, it is `%%A` not `%A`. If you have not changed this, you will have a syntax error that cancels the execution.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but got a "%%A was unxepected at this time" message, so changed it back to %A

Comment: @StuHarper, i don't see how you can get the described behaviour. Can you post (better in a new question, comments are too limited) the code in your batch file?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reaches this, following is working example of batch file to get physical path of iis site , stored in a variable named 'physicalPath'.
This is based on @StuHarper explanations in comments.

```
@echo off
set site=stackoverflow.com
set site=%site:https://=% 
set site=%site:http://=% 
set site=%site: =%

set appcmd=%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe
set xmlOutput=%appcmd% list app /site.name:%site% /path:"/" /xml

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('%xmlOutput% ^| %appcmd% list vdir /in /text:physicalPath') DO SET physcalPath=%%A

echo physcalPath: %physcalPath%
@echo on
```

Comment: I fixed, the set is without " ".

Comment: site should be named without protocol and without space. Added replace to handle name with protocol or trailing space. In addition dont try to copy and run it directly in the console, but save it as batch and then run it (cmd extension)